# Create a random playlist of all music

Tags: ubuntu-one, music, android

I want to listen to all my music streaming to my android phone. How do I create a random playlist with all my music (nearly 14 GB worth of tracks) and then play that one the phone? Do I have to use my Ubuntu laptop to do this and transfer over to the phone, or can the android app do this?

Comment: UbuntuOne i suppose.. or what program exactly..

Comment: @Adam how is this coming along for you?

Comment: @Adam would you consider expanding on your needs or accepting one of the answers below? It is helpful to other users who stumble upon these questions to know which served you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Ubuntu One Music application you can select "Shuffle Play" from the home screen and it will shuffle the music in your Ubuntu One share right to your phone.

[image]

- It is a [commercial service](https://one.ubuntu.com/services/music/) and costs $3.99 a month.

Answer (score 0):

If you want easy streaming from the network, have a look at [MPD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MPD) on your Ubuntu machine, and you can get several clients for the Android phone eg [Droid MPD Client](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.soreha.droidmpdclient&hl=en), as well as for other machines.